# Complicated cross module search in SugarCRM (SuiteCRM)

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I want search by field phone number in many db fields in at least 2 modules.
I have solution, but it is not have optimization and very slow.

My solution:

custom/modules/Accounts/metadata/searchdefs.php

```
 'phone' => array (
    'name' => 'phone',
    'label' => 'LBL_ANY_PHONE',
    'type' => 'name',
    'default' => true,
    'width' => '10%',
  ),
```

custom/modules/Accounts/metadata/SearchFields.php

```
'phone' => array(
  'query_type' => 'default',
  'operator' => 'subquery',
  'subquery' => array(
    'SELECT id FROM accounts a LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ac ON a.id = ac.id_c
     WHERE returnNumericOnly(phone_office_mask_c) LIKE',

    'SELECT id FROM accounts a LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ac ON a.id = ac.id_c
     WHERE returnNumericOnly(phone_fax_mask_c) LIKE',

    'SELECT id FROM accounts a LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ac ON a.id = ac.id_c
     WHERE returnNumericOnly(phone_alternate_mask_c) LIKE',

    'SELECT acc.id FROM accounts acc
       LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts ac_cont ON acc.id = ac_cont.account_id AND ac_cont.deleted = 0
       LEFT JOIN contacts cont ON ac_cont.contact_id = cont.id AND cont.deleted = 0
       LEFT JOIN contacts_cstm cont_c ON cont.id = cont_c.id_c
     WHERE returnNumericOnly(cont_c.phone_mobile_mask_c) LIKE',

    'SELECT acc.id FROM accounts acc
       LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts ac_cont ON acc.id = ac_cont.account_id AND ac_cont.deleted = 0
       LEFT JOIN contacts cont ON ac_cont.contact_id = cont.id AND cont.deleted = 0
       LEFT JOIN contacts_cstm cont_c ON cont.id = cont_c.id_c
     WHERE returnNumericOnly(cont_c.phone_work_mask_c) LIKE',

    'SELECT acc.id FROM accounts acc
       LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts ac_cont ON acc.id = ac_cont.account_id AND ac_cont.deleted = 0
       LEFT JOIN contacts cont ON ac_cont.contact_id = cont.id AND cont.deleted = 0
       LEFT JOIN contacts_cstm cont_c ON cont.id = cont_c.id_c
     WHERE returnNumericOnly(cont_c.phone_fax_mask_c) LIKE',

    'OR' => true
  ),
  'db_field' => array('id')
),
```

But result SQL something like:

```
    SELECT  *
FROM accounts
 LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c
 LEFT JOIN ea1_lead_source jt0 ON accounts_cstm.ea1_lead_source_id_c = jt0.id AND jt0.deleted=0
 LEFT JOIN  users jt1 ON accounts.created_by=jt1.id AND jt1.deleted=0 AND jt1.deleted=0
 LEFT JOIN ea1_region jt2 ON accounts_cstm.ea1_region_id_c = jt2.id AND jt2.deleted=0
WHERE
((

accounts.id IN (
  SELECT id FROM accounts a LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ac ON a.id = ac.id_c
        WHERE phone_office_mask_c LIKE '749577%') 

OR  accounts.id IN (
  SELECT id FROM accounts a LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ac ON a.id = ac.id_c
        WHERE phone_fax_mask_c LIKE '749577%')

OR  accounts.id IN (
  SELECT id FROM accounts a LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm ac ON a.id = ac.id_c
        WHERE phone_alternate_mask_c LIKE '749577%')

OR  accounts.id IN (
  SELECT acc.id FROM accounts acc LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts ac_cont ON acc.id = ac_cont.account_id AND ac_cont.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN contacts cont ON ac_cont.contact_id = cont.id AND cont.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN contacts_cstm cont_c ON cont.id = cont_c.id_c
        WHERE returnNumericOnly(cont_c.phone_mobile_mask_c) LIKE '749577%')

OR  accounts.id IN (
  SELECT acc.id FROM accounts acc
          LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts ac_cont ON acc.id = ac_cont.account_id AND ac_cont.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN contacts cont ON ac_cont.contact_id = cont.id AND cont.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN contacts_cstm cont_c ON cont.id = cont_c.id_c
        WHERE returnNumericOnly(cont_c.phone_work_mask_c) LIKE '749577%')

OR  accounts.id IN (
  SELECT acc.id FROM accounts acc
          LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts ac_cont ON acc.id = ac_cont.account_id AND ac_cont.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN contacts cont ON ac_cont.contact_id = cont.id AND cont.deleted = 0
          LEFT JOIN contacts_cstm cont_c ON cont.id = cont_c.id_c
        WHERE returnNumericOnly(cont_c.phone_fax_mask_c) LIKE '749577%')

))
AND accounts.deleted=0
ORDER BY accounts.name ASC
```

I want result search SQL without subqueries, something like:

```
    SELECT *
FROM accounts acc
  LEFT JOIN accounts_cstm acc_c ON accounts.id = accounts_cstm.id_c
  LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts ac_cont ON acc.id = ac_cont.account_id AND ac_cont.deleted = 0
  LEFT JOIN contacts cont ON ac_cont.contact_id = cont.id AND cont.deleted = 0
  LEFT JOIN contacts_cstm cont_c ON cont.id = cont_c.id_c
  LEFT JOIN ...
WHERE 
  acc_c.phone_office_mask_c LIKE '749577%'
  AND acc_c.phone_fax_mask_c LIKE '749577%'
  AND acc_c.phone_alternate_mask_c LIKE '749577%'
  AND cont_c.phone_mobile_mask_c LIKE '749577%'
  AND cont_c.phone_work_mask_c LIKE '749577%'
  AND cont_c.phone_fax_mask_c LIKE '749577%'
  AND ….
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the subquery operator it will do a subquery.

You can get more information from source code here `include/SearchForm/SearchForm2.php#L1164`

There is ANY PHONE search on contacts for example, why not use that as a base?